# How to use this function to apply to each row？

Tags: pandas, apply

I have a dataframe with thousands of rows, a part of the dataframe is shown in the figure:
[image]

I defined two functions：

```
def zspread_solution(x):
    FV = x[1]
    COUPON_RATE = x[2]
    T = x[3]
    N = x[4]
    C = COUPON_RATE * T * N
    fun = - FV
    for item_index in range(int(x[5] + 1)):
        if item_index != x[5]:
            DELTA_T = (item_index + 1) * T
            rate = df[item_index + 1] + x[0]
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = C/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
        else:
            DELTA_T = item_index * T
            rate = df[item_index] + x[0]
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = N/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
        return fun

def fun_solve(df):
    closing_price = df['closing_price']
    coupon_rate = df['coupon_rate']
    Interest_payment_interval = df['Interest_payment_interval']
    face_value = df['face_value']
    Interest_payment_time = df['Interest_payment_time']

    x = [0, closing_price, coupon_rate, Interest_payment_interval, face_value, 
        Interest_payment_time]
    return fsolve(zspread_solution, x)[0]
```

I want to call the fun_solve function to calculate a constant for each row.

```
df['zspread'] = df.apply(fun_solve, axis=1)
```

But it's raise an Error:

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'zspread_solution'.Shape should be (6,) but it is (1050,)
```

I successfully calculated the zspread for each row using 'for' and 'loc':

```
def fu(x): 
    fun = - FV
    for item_index in range(int(TIM + 1)):
        if item_index != TIM:
            DELTA_T = (item_index + 1) * T
            rate = df.loc[0, item_index + 1] + x
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = C/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
        else:
            DELTA_T = item_index * T
            rate = df.loc[0, item_index] + x
            NUMERATOR = (1 + rate)**DELTA_T
            item = N/NUMERATOR
            fun += item
        return fun

zsp = []
for index in df.index:
    FV = df.loc[index, 'closing_price']
    COUPON_RATE = df.loc[index, 'coupon_rate']
    T = df.loc[index, 'Interest_payment_interval']
    N = df.loc[index, 'face_value']
    C = COUPON_RATE * T * N
    TIM = df.loc[index, 'Interest_payment_time']
    item = fsolve(fu, 0)[0]
    zsp.append(item)
df['zspread'] = zsp
```

But I still want to know how to use apply to achieve this calculation.

Here is some data：

```
closing_price:107.7301, 106.0029, 105.1495, 105.2768
coupon_rate:4.39, 3.65, 3.6, 3.66
Interest_payment_time:8, 20, 20, 15
Interest_payment_interval:1, 1, 1, 1
face_value:100, 100, 100, 100
0:0.01342
1:0.021977
2:0.022843
3:0.023907
4:0.02465
5:0.025296
6:0.026264
7：0.0268
8：0.026793
9：0.026781
10：0.026776
11：0.026875
12：0.027104
13：0.0274
14：0.027702
15：0.027947
16：0.028099
17：0.028181
18：0.028221
19：0.028247
20：0.028288
21：0.028368
22：0.028487
```

Comment: `df.apply(fun_solve, args=('a', 'b', 'c'), axis=1)` / `df.apply(fun_solve, name1='a', name2='b', axis=1)`

Comment: But given you `fun_solve` function takes a `df` as input, you might want `fun_solve(df, arg, kwarg='a')` (of course adding parameters to the function)

Comment: I modified the code as follows： df.apply(fun_solve, args=('closing_price', 'coupon_rate', 'Interest_payment_interval', 'face_value', 'Interest_payment_time'), axis=1) , def fun_solve(df, closing_price, coupon_rate, Interest_payment_interval, face_value, Interest_payment_time):， it's still can't run successfully